# How to fix bad edit of reviewer

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have made [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1241400) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809421/google-maps-embed-into-site-without-popup-window/9809583#9809583). My suggestion was rejected, but the edit done by reviewer is wrong. He added the link like the code, but there was bold text (`**iwloc=near**`) he didn't see. How can I fix that, it says that I need to fix at least 6 characters, but there is only 4 to remove.

Here is also [revisions history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9809583/revisions) of the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really necessary for that part of the URL to remain bold, as it's explained what was changed in the URL in the sentence above, but leaving the asterisks in there looks odd since they don't get rendered. I've modified the post to point out the change in a different way (as well as removing the annoying syntax highlighting).